# Change line spacing for a table inside a document

Tags: tables, spacing, line-spacing

I am writing a document using `agujournal2018.cls` template. The template could be found [here](https://publications.agu.org/author-resource-center/checklists-and-templates/).

I have a lengthy table inside my document which do not fit A4 page with double spacing. I want minimum possible spacing for the table without affecting the rest of the document, so it fits in a single page.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}` in your table/tabular environment? That should help in resetting the double spacing to single spacing for the table.

Comment: @mas: worked. Provide as a answer. BTW do journals allow `\renewcommand`?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be allowed! It's all the same LaTeX after all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the interrow spacing in a table using `arraystretch` command. Similarly, `tabcolsep` will control the spacing between columns (if you need it).
Here is the snippet you can use:

```
\begin{table}\centering                                                                                                                                                                   
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}                                                                                                                                                        
%\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1em}                                                                                                                                                           
\begin{tabular}{llcr}                                                                                                                                                                     
...                                                                                                                                                                                          
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                             
\end{table
```